# JSTL format tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a custom `java.text.Format` and would like to use it in my JSP. Is there a JSP/JSTL tag that can format an object using a custom `java.text.Format`? I'm looking for something similar to `<fmt:formatNumber>` and `<fmt:formatDate>` except that an custom format can be used.

I know that I can write my own tag but am curious if there's an existing solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. You have to write your own custom tag.